# XML/XSD graphical representation of the tree

Tags: xml, xsd, visualization

I have constructed a XML file and generated a XSD file from it. The XML is almost empty as there are elements but without value :

```
<parent>
   <child1/>
   <child2/>
</parent>
```

What I'm looking for is a soft that could convert my XML (or its associated schema) into a graphical representation as a tree :

```
                parent
                   |
                   |
     _______________________________
     |                             |
     |                             |
   child1                        child2
```

with cute boxes, colors and so on.

Any suggestion ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it would be helpful to understand why you would be doing it for; for example, to author/analyse/validate the source (XML or XSD) and/or for documentation purposes? Then how do you plan on doing it? Interactive? Do you need automation to extract the visualizations?

A number of open source and free editions of commercial products provide some sort of XML and XSD visualization: Eclipse, NetBeans, Visual Studio (development tools), HelpStudio (help authoring), Oxygen, XmlSpy (specialized editors), etc.

[QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) also provides graphical representations of XML and XSD files; below are some examples.

XML visualized as a tree:

[image]

The associated (inferred) XSD:

[image]

The tools comes with an automation API that would allow one to constantly update these diagrams as the underlying XML/XSD changes.

Comment: My need is quite simple and straightforward. I have kind of a decision tree. This tree is too large to be plotted with word smartart so I looked for another tool. XML is very convenient to represent a tree because it is its proper philosophy. However, looking at a XML file with NotePadXML or whatever the soft is not of practical interest. The first representation you gave is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

**XSDDiagram**, a small .NET 2.0 open source application can generate those diagrams.

http://regis.cosnier.free.fr/?page=XSDDiagram