# Graphical representation of A DOM tree

Tags: xml

Is there anything that I can use to make a visual representation of the nodes in a x ml file.I have tried to find something but up till now nothing.

Comment: Draw a picture of what you had in mind and post it here.

Comment: So I have XML and want to have something like this but with graphics or something

Blog
    Authors
        Author
           name
             surname

and so on..

Comment: posssibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955542/xml-xsd-graphical-representation-of-the-tree?rq=1

Comment: I va already found that solution but it is not what i am looking for :/ thanks anyways